# How can wait_timeout/interactive_timeout be ignored?

Tags: mysql, timeout, wait

My mySQL server is not respecting wait_timeout or interactive_timeout of 15 seconds. Queries just keep going and going past the respective 15 seconds. Below is the my.cnf -

```
[mysqld]

# Settings user and group are ignored when systemd is used (fedora >= 15).
# If you need to run mysqld under different user or group,
# customize your systemd unit file for mysqld according to the
# instructions in http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Systemd
user=mysql
#skip-innodb

#ignore-builtin-innodb
#default-storage-engine = myisam
#log-queries-not-using-indexes

#key_buffer              = 6M
key_buffer_size         = 1024M
max_allowed_packet      = 64M
thread_stack            = 256K
thread_cache_size       = 200
max_connections         = 200
table_cache             = 128K
tmp_table_size          = 24M
max_heap_table_size     = 24M
join_buffer_size        = 1M
query_cache_limit       = 32M
query_cache_size        = 8M
read_buffer_size        = 1M
# concurrent_insert       = ALWAYS

general_log = 0
general_log_file = /var/log/mysql/general.log

low_priority_updates=1

log_warnings=2
#log_error=/var/log/mysql/mysql_error.log
slow-query-log                  = 1
slow-query-log-file = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
long_query_time=1

wait_timeout=15
interactive_timeout=15

datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

# InnoDB Settings
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 768M
innodb_log_file_size = 100M
innodb-file-per-table          = 1

# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

# Semisynchronous Replication
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-semisync.html
# uncomment next line on MASTER
#;plugin-load=rpl_semi_sync_master=semisync_master.so
# uncomment next line on SLAVE
#;plugin-load=rpl_semi_sync_slave=semisync_slave.so

# Others options for Semisynchronous Replication
#;rpl_semi_sync_master_enabled=1
#;rpl_semi_sync_master_timeout=10
#;rpl_semi_sync_slave_enabled=1

# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/performance-schema.html
#;performance_schema

#log-queries-not-using-indexes

default-storage-engine=MyISAM
#log-queries-not-using-indexes

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

I ran the command on the server, but when I do mytop - there are queries that are more then 15 seconds.

```
mysql> select @@global.wait_timeout, @@session.wait_timeout;
+-----------------------+------------------------+
| @@global.wait_timeout | @@session.wait_timeout |
+-----------------------+------------------------+
|                    15 |                     15 |
+-----------------------+------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wait_timeout` is documented as follows:

> The number of seconds the server waits for activity on a
>   noninteractive connection before closing it. This timeout applies only
>   to TCP/IP and Unix socket file connections, not to connections made
>   using named pipes, or shared memory.

From your question it sounds like you're trying to use it and `interactive_timeout` abruptly to abandon long-running queries.  But that's not what it's for.

Comment: I found a bash script that will remove queries that have been running for more then 60 seconds.